# Aumented reality not working properly in my game

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, openxr, ar-foundation

i am using the AR foundation toolkit with OpenXR to implement AR in my VR game,the problem is that that require to set solid color in the camera setting,i set it up but when i start the game i see the real world with the color that i set up in the camera.I tryed to set skybox like background type but in that case AR doesn't work.
this is a video of the error https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=em6SiaOlkmU.
I also attached the screen of my camera settings,can you help me?

I tryed to change color and set skybox like camera mode but nothing.
I expect to solve my problem.

Comment: looks more like fog to me

Comment: No i set grey like solid color in the camera it is not fog,the problem is that it should not do this effect